# Angular animation style lost after animation ends

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I have a very simple animation that is triggered as the elemnt comes into view

```
const transAnimation = trigger("myAnimationTrigger", [
    transition('void => *', [
      query('.circle-chart', [
        animate('4s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)'),
        style({'stroke-dashoffset': 200}),
      ])
    ])
]);
```

But after animation ends the style is values are lost. How to make style values permanent.

```
<div class="circle">
   <div [@myAnimationTrigger] class="pie">
       <svg>
          <circle class="circle-chart" id="circle-graph" cx="60"
                  cy="60"
                   r="50">
          </circle>
       </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

scss code

```
.circle {  
   width: 125px;
   height: 125px;
   border: 3px solid #5b5f78;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;
}

.pie {
   position: relative;
   width: 119px;
   height: 119px;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
   svg circle {
       fill: transparent;
       stroke: #4356d6;
       stroke-width: 14;
       stroke-dasharray: 360;
       stroke-dashoffset: 360;
       animation: pieChart 3.8s ease forwards;
   }
}
```

Comment: this is not posible as of i know